# If I borrow license from a concurrent ArcGIS license server will the server license count gets decreased?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-license-manager

If I borrow one license from my ArcGIS concurrent license server will the server count get reduced? Altogether the institute is having 5 licenses; if I borrow 1 will the available ArcGIS license count be reduced to 4?

Comment: Is your question about ArcGIS Server (as written) or about ArcGIS Desktop license server (your apparent meaning)?

Comment: Yes arcgis desktop license server. If I borrow will the server count will get decreased that was my question

Comment: That's the definition of borrowing -- checking out a seat indefinitely. It would be worthless license management technology if you could check out a seat and still let others use it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, borrowing a license means it will be unavailable for use by anybody else until you check it back in.  You don't suddenly gain an extra license.

See [Borrowing and returning concurrent use licenses](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/get-started/administering-desktop/borrowing-and-returning-licenses.htm)

Also note:

> The timeout for borrowed licenses is defined by your license
>   administrator. Contact your organization's license administrator to
>   change this value. The default timeout is 30 days. If licenses are not
>   returned within that time, they will automatically be disabled on your
>   machine and reenabled on the license manager.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. It seems the question wants to know if borrowing a Desktop license reduces the Server count. Server seats are not permitted to be concurrent, so the question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Vince the title says *from a concurrent ArcGIS license server*, I don't believe this question is anything to do with ArcGIS Server itself.